# Creating an sql database script with tables with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

For a database creation exercise, I am trying to create a database with the following script which gives the error:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `qr_bottle`.`invoice` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I'm not sure to understand the problem, 
should I create all the tables without foreign keys and alter the tables after they are all created to add the keys?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Qr_Bottle
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Qr_Bottle
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle` ;
USE `Qr_Bottle` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Client`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `First_Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Last_Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Phone_Number` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Payment_Method` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Qr_Code` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Date` DATETIME NULL,
  `Nbr_Of_Client` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Client_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Client_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Client_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Role`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Role` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Role` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `First_Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Last_Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Role_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Role_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Role_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Role` (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking_has_Staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking_has_Staff` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking_has_Staff` (
  `Booking_Id` INT NULL,
  `Staff_Id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Booking_Id`, `Staff_Id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Booking_Id`)
    REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` (`Id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Staff_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

  -- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` DATETIME NULL,
  `Price` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Vat` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Order_Id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Order_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Booking_Id` INT NULL,
  `Product_Id` INT NULL,
  `Invoice_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Invoice_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Booking_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Product_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Invoice_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Capacity` INT NULL,
  `Order_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_Type_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Order_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Product_Type_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Stock`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Stock` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Stock` (
  `Product_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Product_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Spot`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Spot` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Spot` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Client_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Client_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Client_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method_has_Client`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method_has_Client` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method_has_Client` (
  `Payment_Method_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Client_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Payment_Method_Id`, `Client_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Payment_Method_Id`)
  REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method` (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Client_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (`Id`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table order product and invoice are interlinkt, you can only add a foreign after the referenced table was created, so you have to alter the table after creating the referenced table

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Qr_Bottle
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Qr_Bottle
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle` ;
USE `Qr_Bottle` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Client`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `First_Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Last_Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Phone_Number` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Payment_Method` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Qr_Code` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Date` DATETIME NULL,
  `Nbr_Of_Client` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Client_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Client_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Client_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Role`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Role` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Role` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `First_Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Last_Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Role_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Role_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Role_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Role` (`Id`));


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking_has_Staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking_has_Staff` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking_has_Staff` (
  `Booking_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Staff_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Booking_Id`, `Staff_Id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Booking_Id`)
    REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` (`Id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Staff_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Staff` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

  -- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` DATETIME NULL,
  `Price` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Vat` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Order_Id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Booking_Id` INT NULL,
  `Product_Id` INT NULL,
  `Invoice_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Invoice_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Booking_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Booking` (`Id`)
,
  FOREIGN KEY (`Invoice_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice` (`Id`));

ALTER TABLE `Qr_Bottle`.`Invoice`
ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`Order_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` (`Id`); 
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `Capacity` INT NULL,
  `Order_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_Type_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Order_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Order` (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Product_Type_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Product_Type` (`Id`));

ALTER TABLE `Qr_Bottle`.`Order`
ADD    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` (`Id`); 
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Stock`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Stock` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Stock` (
  `Product_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Product_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Product` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Spot`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Spot` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Spot` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Client_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `Client_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Client_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method_has_Client`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method_has_Client` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method_has_Client` (
  `Payment_Method_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Client_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Payment_Method_Id`, `Client_Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Payment_Method_Id`)
  REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Payment_Method` (`Id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Client_Id`) REFERENCES `Qr_Bottle`.`Client` (`Id`));
```